# Duplicate unique property 'sameAs' in JSON

Tags: json, seo, schema, json-ld

The HTML Schema for sameAs:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
      <h1><span itemprop="name">Business Name</span></h1>
      <span itemprop="description">Business Desciription.</span>
      <span itemprop="sameAs">fb.com</span>
      <span itemprop="sameAs">pinterest.com</span>
      <span itemprop="sameAs">instagram.com</span>
  </div>
```

Google Validation Tool: sameAs has **no Duplicate unique property** error.
[image]

For Json sameAs: **Duplicate unique property** error occurs

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "@id": "http://schema.org/",
    "name": "Business Name",
    "email": "help@example.com",
    "priceRange": "$$$",
    "sameAs": "https://www.facebook.com/",
    "sameAs":"https://twitter.com/",
    "sameAs":"https://www.instagram.com/",         
    "sameAs":"https://au.linkedin.com/company/",
    "sameAs":"https://www.yelp.com.au/"
   }
```

Google Validation Tool: Error **Duplicate unique property**
[image]

Question:
How do I fix the **Duplicate unique property** in JSON?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the items as an array for it to be valid `JSON+LD`.

If you think about it, that is logical, as otherwise if you turned the JSON into plain JavaScript you would just be overwriting the `sameAs` variable each time.

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "@id": "http://schema.org/",
    "name": "Business Name",
    "email": "help@example.com",
    "priceRange": "$$$",
    "sameAs": [
               "https://www.facebook.com/",
               "https://twitter.com/",
               "https://www.instagram.com/",         
               "https://au.linkedin.com/company/",
               "https://www.yelp.com.au/"
              ]
}
```